# Android: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I keep on having a `NUllPointerException` on the line:

```
return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

I don't know why. Can anyone help me? This is the SQLite database of my app:

```
public MessagesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's null? At least some of the stack trace might be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like mDb isn't getting set. Have you called open() before calling createNote? Otherwise try adding a call to open() in the createNote method like this:

```
public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
    initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

    open();

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```